# Tag synonym disappeared without a trace?

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I suggested [gtk+] and [gtk2] tag synonyms for the [gtk] tag; by the next day they had disappeared without a trace. Does that mean they were voted down to -2 and therefore rejected? If so, I would like to place a feature request for being notified when that happens.

Comment: List of rejected synonyms to avoid confusion and duplication of effort, you say?  Why, that's just crazy enough to work!  (+1)

Comment: Hm, a notification might even help with the education of those users that don't get synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

+1 because it's a good idea, but for the record: gtk+ and gtk2 are not good synonyms for gtk.  Specifications of a generic topic are not good candidate for synonyms.

Comment: Well, that's why I would have liked to be able to discuss that. I agree, having thought more about it, that [gtk2] isn't (although [gtk2] questions should be retagged as [gtk] unless they specifically refer to the GTK 2.x line), but GTK+ is the full name of the toolkit that everybody refers to as GTK. Nothing to do with being more or less specific.